# R Package Organization

Tags: r, r-package

I've been creating an R package for my own use, both for utility but also as a learning exercise. I've been scrupulously following the direction in Hadley Wickham's ["R Packages" book](https://r-pkgs.org/index.html).

Some of my package's functions create tables and charts. The functions have an option to save these artifacts as a PNG graphic. When I do that, I'd like to include a logo in the output.

I know how to place the logo and save the file; what I'm struggling with is where in the package folder hierarchy I would correctly store static files like the logo.

From my reading, it seems an `inst` folder, such as `inst/graphics`, might be the right place, but I'd be interested in feedback from more experienced package developers.

Comment: I always use inst for anything external, it gets bloated but gets the job done

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Bruno. I presume, then, you just load the resource (in my case, a logo) directly from that folder, i.e., ```image_read("inst/graphics/logo.png)```.

Comment: That is how I do it on my blog, on packages I never worked with pictures but if it is the same as data I have started to migrate for workflow tools like the targets package, if you nedd documentation just use the classic use_data_raw() approch from usethis and then document the r object on the R/ folder

Comment: You might put it in the subdirectory `/data`  as discussed in the `R_exts` manual